# methods being called twice in android

Tags: android, android-volley

I am developing a quiz app for my collegial event. We have four types of three questions :Image base,Sql ,Direction Sense and Code snippets. We proceed to the next questions when either the timer runs out or the player has clicked the next button. Now, in case of the timer, the rand() method is being called twice. Logs suggest me that its called twice from within the timer onfinish().We assume a maximum of 12 questions currently.

Here is the code for the Question Activity:

```
public class Question extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView quesimage;
private TextView timer;
private RadioGroup optionsgroup;
private int quesid;
private RadioButton one, two, three, four;
private TextView questionTextView;
private boolean flag = true;
private int count = 0;
private int time;
int arr[][] = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1,    2, 1}, {2, 0, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 0, 1}, {3, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 1}};

//TODO question recurrence fix.//High priority.
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.question_layout);
    quesimage = findViewById(R.id.quesimage);
    timer = findViewById(R.id.timer);
    questionTextView = findViewById(R.id.questext);
    optionsgroup = findViewById(R.id.optionsgroup);
    one = findViewById(R.id.optionone);
    two = findViewById(R.id.optiontwo);
    three = findViewById(R.id.optionthree);
    four = findViewById(R.id.optionfour);
    final Button nextquestion = findViewById(R.id.nextquestion);
    rand();
    nextquestion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            submitoptionSelected();


        }
    });
    reverseTimer(time, timer);
}

private void submitoptionSelected() {
    int optid = 0;
    final int teamid = getSharedPreferences(Config.Shared_ID_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(Config.KEY_ID, 0);
    Log.d("teamid", "" + teamid);
    if (one.isChecked()) {
        optid = 1;
    } else if (two.isChecked()) {
        optid = 2;
    } else if (three.isChecked()) {
        optid = 3;
    } else if (four.isChecked()) {
        optid = 4;
    }
    final int finalOptid = optid;
    final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.SUBMIT_OPTIONS_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("Success") ||  response.equalsIgnoreCase("Updated succesfully")) {
                optionsgroup.clearCheck();
                while (!flag) {
                    flag = true;
                    Log.d("randcall", "I am being called from options");
                    rand();
                }
                rand();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("error", "" + error.getMessage());

        }
    })

    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            final Map<String, String> selectedmap = new HashMap<>();
            selectedmap.put(Config.KEY_ID, String.valueOf(teamid));
            Log.d("ids", "" + teamid + "  " + quesid);
            selectedmap.put(Config.KEY_QUESTION_ID, String.valueOf(quesid));
            selectedmap.put(Config.KEY_OPTION_ID, String.valueOf(finalOptid));
            return selectedmap;
        }
    };
    Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(stringRequest);

}


private void getImage(final int id, final String sendtype, final String sendlvl) {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Question.this, "PLease wait", "Loading");
    progressDialog.show();
    final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.IMAGE_QUESTIONS_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("image", response);
            try {
                parseQuestionsResponse(response);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("errorimage", "" + error.getMessage());
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put(Config.KEY_ID, String.valueOf(id));
            map.put(Config.KEY_TYPE, sendtype);
            map.put(Config.KEY_LEVEL, sendlvl);
            return map;
        }
    };
    Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(stringRequest);


}

private void parseQuestionsResponse(String response) throws JSONException {
    final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    final JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("questions");
    int randnum;
    int count = 0;
    count++;
    Log.d("callcount", "" + count + " " + " " + quesid + " " + array.length());


    if (array.length() == 0) {

        rand();
    } else {
        randnum = new Random().nextInt(array.length());
        JSONObject quesobj = array.getJSONObject(randnum);
        Log.d("old", "" + quesid);
        Log.d("old1", "" + quesobj.getInt("QuesId"));

        quesid = quesobj.getInt("QuesId");
        Log.d("quesid", "" + quesid);
        String ques = quesobj.getString("Question");
        String purl = quesobj.getString("PhotoURL");
        time = quesobj.getInt("Time");
        questionTextView.setText(ques);
        quesimage.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + purl, null, getPackageName()));
        getOptions();
    }

}


private void getOptions() {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Question.this, "Loading", "Please wait");
    progressDialog.show();
    final Request.Priority priority = Request.Priority.HIGH;
    final StringRequest optionsRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.OPTIONS_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            try {
                parseOptions(response);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("error", "" + error.getMessage());
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            final Map<String, String> optionsmap = new HashMap<>();
            optionsmap.put(Config.KEY_ID, String.valueOf(quesid));
            return optionsmap;
        }

        @Override
        public Priority getPriority() {
            return priority;
        }

    };
    Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(optionsRequest);
}

private void parseOptions(String response) throws JSONException {
    final JSONObject optionsobj = new JSONObject(response);
    final JSONArray jsonArray = optionsobj.getJSONArray("questions");
    final JSONObject option1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
    final JSONObject option2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1);
    final JSONObject option3 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(2);
    final JSONObject option4 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(3);
    one.setText(option1.getString("question"));
    two.setText(option2.getString("question"));
    three.setText(option3.getString("question"));
    four.setText(option4.getString("question"));
    count++;
    Log.d("fetch", "" + time);
    reverseTimer(time, timer);

}
public void rand() {
    Log.d("count", "" + count);


    final Random rand = new Random();
    if (count == 12) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Question.this, MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
        return;

    }
    final int qtype = rand.nextInt(4);
    final int qlevel = rand.nextInt(3);
    final String[] type = {"Image", "SQL", "DS", "CS"};
    final String[] level = {"Easy", "Medium", "Hard"};
    String sendtype;
    String sendlvl;
    switch (qtype) {
        case 0:
            switch (qlevel) {
                case 0: {
                    if (arr[0][2] > 0) {
                        sendtype = type[qtype];
                        sendlvl = level[qlevel];
                        arr[0][2]--;
                        getImage(getSharedPreferences(Config.Shared_ID_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(Config.KEY_ID, 0), sendtype, sendlvl);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        flag = false;
                        return;
                    }

                }

                case 1: {
                    if (arr[1][2] > 0) {
                        sendtype = type[qtype];
                        sendlvl = level[qlevel];
                        arr[1][2]--;
                        getImage(getSharedPreferences(Config.Shared_ID_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(Config.KEY_ID, 0), sendtype, sendlvl);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        flag = false;
                        return;
                    }

                }

                case 2:

                {
                    if (arr[2][2] > 0) {
                        sendtype = type[qtype];
                        sendlvl = level[qlevel];
                        arr[2][2]--;
                        getImage(getSharedPreferences(Config.Shared_ID_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(Config.KEY_ID, 0), sendtype, sendlvl);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        flag = false;
                        return;
                    }

                }
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            switch (qlevel) {
                case 0: {
                    if (arr[3][2] > 0) {
                        sendtype = type[qtype];
                        sendlvl = level[qlevel];
                        arr[3][2]--;
                        getImage(getSharedPreferences(Config.Shared_ID_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(Config.KEY_ID, 0), sendtype, sendlvl);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        flag = false;
                        return;
                    }

                }

                case 1:

                {
                    if (arr[4][2] > 0) {
                        sendtype = type[qtype];
                        sendlvl = level[qlevel];
                        arr[4][2]--;
                        getImage(getSharedPreferences(Config.Shared_ID_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(Config.KEY_ID, 0), sendtype, sendlvl);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        flag = false;
                        return;
                    }

                }
                case 2:

                {
                    if (arr[5][2] > 0) {
                        sendtype = type[qtype];
                        sendlvl = level[qlevel];
                        arr[5][2]--;
                        getImage(getSharedPreferences(Config.Shared_ID_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(Config.KEY_ID, 0), sendtype, sendlvl);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        flag = false;
                        return;
                    }

                }

            }
            break;
        case 2:
            switch (qlevel) {
                case 0:
                    if (arr[6][2] > 0) {
                        sendtype = type[qtype];
                        sendlvl = level[qlevel];
                        arr[6][2]--;
                        getImage(getSharedPreferences(Config.Shared_ID_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(Config.KEY_ID, 0), sendtype, sendlvl);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        flag = false;
                        return;
                    }

                case 1:
                    if (arr[7][2] > 0) {
                        sendtype = type[qtype];
                        sendlvl = level[qlevel];
                        arr[7][2]--;
                        getImage(getSharedPreferences(Config.Shared_ID_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(Config.KEY_ID, 0), sendtype, sendlvl);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        flag = false;
                        return;
                    }

                case 2:
                    if (arr[8][2] > 0) {
                        sendtype = type[qtype];
                        sendlvl = level[qlevel];
                        arr[8][2]--;
                        getImage(getSharedPreferences(Config.Shared_ID_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(Config.KEY_ID, 0), sendtype, sendlvl);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        flag = false;
                        return;
                    }


            }
            break;
        case 3:
            switch (qlevel) {
                case 0:
                    if (arr[9][2] > 0) {
                        sendtype = type[qtype];
                        sendlvl = level[qlevel];
                        arr[9][2]--;
                        getImage(getSharedPreferences(Config.Shared_ID_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(Config.KEY_ID, 0), sendtype, sendlvl);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        flag = false;
                        return;
                    }

                case 1:
                    if (arr[10][2] > 0) {
                        sendtype = type[qtype];
                        sendlvl = level[qlevel];
                        arr[10][2]--;
                        getImage(getSharedPreferences(Config.Shared_ID_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(Config.KEY_ID, 0), sendtype, sendlvl);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        flag = false;
                        return;
                    }

                case 2:
                    if (arr[11][2] > 0) {
                        sendtype = type[qtype];
                        sendlvl = level[qlevel];
                        arr[11][2]--;
                        getImage(getSharedPreferences(Config.Shared_ID_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(Config.KEY_ID, 0), sendtype, sendlvl);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        flag = false;
                        return;
                    }


            }
            break;


    }


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Question.this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure to exit?");
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

}

public void reverseTimer(int Seconds, final TextView tv) {


    new CountDownTimer(Seconds * 1000 + 1000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            int minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;
            tv.setText("TIME : " + String.format("%02d", minutes)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds));
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            submitoptionSelected();
            rand();

        }
    }.start();
}
```

}

Comment: too much code in my opinion

Comment: is it from stringRequest's onResponse?

Comment: @SivakumarS I logged a statement inside the count down time and it appears twice at each new question suggesting that is where the issue is.

Comment: it is a lot of code to post without a specific question.  Might be better to run the code in a debugger and identify the code path and re-ask the question if it still isn't clear why the function is being called twice.

Comment: Okay let it be.